# Styling Django Autocomplete Light

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using Django Crispy forms with the tailwind template pack to render out my form, I need autocomplete functionality to be able to search for and select an `ingredient`. The only viable package I could find is DAL (Django Autocomplete Light). The problem I am facing now is that I can't override the styling so that it looks the same as my other fields. If someone could point me in a direction of how I can achieve this I would be very grateful :)

1. overiding the widget attrs (as shown below) does not do it as this affects the select element which is hidden by DAL

my form field:
`ingredient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ingredient.objects.all(), widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(attrs={'class': '*my_tailwind_classes*'}))`

[image]

Comment: Use css. Write custom css to match the look and add style to your page.